# PHP Error, "session_start(): - failed: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I installed a CMS on my website called Fusion-CMS.

However, when I install it/move it to a folder (say, www.example.com/cms/), I get this annoying error on top and won't modules from the CMS work properly!

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: session_start(): open(../tmp\sess_mpnr120ag1dg5mfr1mon7dd6m1, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 33
```

But if I install it/move it back to root folder (www.example.com/) it will work without any errors. But I need it on the folder! This CMS uses CI (CodeIgniter) if it's of any relevance, as I searched for similar topics on google and some say it might be CI.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Wolfgang1983, here's what I found.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 18000;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 18000;
```

Comment: You could use codeigniter sessions http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sessions

Comment: Is session.save_path set to an relative path (or is this something codeigniter does)? If it is a relative path chaning it to an absolute path should fix that. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Answer (score 0):

On your config.php make sure you have set your path correct.

I have set mine up in systems directory there for I use BASEPATH. You could set it up in APPPATH which is your application folder.

Make sure you have a `$config['encryption_key'] = 'some_secure_key';`

`$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';`

Update

Session configuration

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cookie_monster';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

**Update**

Since your sessions look like codeigniter 2

Looks like codeigiter 2 your using then need to configure your sessions like says in codeigniter 2 user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 18000;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE; // FALSE to TRUE
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 18000;
```

Insert this into your sessions table from user guide

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Comment: Hi wolfgang1983, I could only find this on my config.php on my applications folder. Check EDIT.

Comment: Codeigniter 2 session user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I did what you said. I set `$config['sess_use_database']` to true, and, as that table already existed, I deleted it and uploaded the new one you provided me. Sadly, the error is still present... I've pastebinned session.php and config.php for you.[link](http://pastebin.com/m5RvVzMP) and [link](http://pastebin.com/2wGYKAtR) . Thanks.

Comment: are you setting codeigniter session there way by using s $this->session->set_userdata etc.

Comment: I don't know, how can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set your configuration correctly.
Try to change your configuration something like this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 18000;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 18000;
```

Instead change it to something like this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session'; // name of your session
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200; // the session expiration last ,you can set it to zero for no expiration
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE; //
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I hope this helps you. For more information try to search about CodeIgniter manual.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

My friend got on tv and after a few minutes he fixed it by moving the tmp folder to the root of the site. According to my friend "tmp folder must always be one folder behind the CMS".